# The difficulties of editing a BCD Store on a cloned system drive

Tags: windows, uefi, clone, bcd

**Problem**: Booting from a cloned NVME drive / EFI System Partition still boots into the old OS system drive. I want it to boot into the new drive's OS and get it assigned as C.

**Context**: I've rolled this Windows 10 OS several times with drive upgrades. I used to use XXClone, which had an option that sorted out the BCD info automatically for the new device, but that product, as I'm sure many know, is sadly unusable now since the developer passed away and the license verification domain expired.

So I just cloned my system NVME to a bigger stick using Rescuezilla (500GB in 5 minutes, not bad!)

Using Visual BCD, I can open the BCD Store on the new drive's ESP by using DISKPART to assign a drive letter and switching to that store at /efi/microsoft/boot/bcd

I want to add an entry that will boot from the new drive instead.

**Where I am stuck**
What I see in Visual BCD is a bit confusing -
I have a {bootmgr} entry with an element called ApplicationDevice that points at volume8. This is the old drive's Windows partition. And an Application path that correctly points to the EFI boot manager.

[image: Entries in {bootmgr}]

I think this (whichever location it runs from) loads some variables from the board's NVRAM, but I don't know if those matter in terms of the OS which gets loaded. So I thought, as step 1, I should at least change the ApplicationDevice entry to point at the new drive, but if I try to edit it, I get a completely different dialog than I would expect, which seems to be creating a new entry, none of which can have the Name "ApplicationDevice" (though it has that as the Dialog Title) and it asks for a drive and path, not just a volume descriptor like the existing entry. I did try editing one of these, and it SEEMS that if you edit the dialog, it fills out both ApplicationDevice and ApplicationPath elements with the choices in this dialog - I picked PartitionDevice from the list, and that seems to have no effect good or bad or visible, maybe it affects how the entries in the other fields are interpreted?

[image: Edit button dialog]

Then my second confusion is around the Loaders - I assume that these define where the system OS gets booted from, and I have some weird stuff in here, which may be a symptom of having cloned more than once over the years.

I've got a few Loader entries - the one it seems to choose (it doesn't offer a selection) is called Windows 10 and looks like this.

[image: Windows10 Loader elements]

I am really after some advice on what I can and should change with whatever tools to get this, just very cleanly booting the new system.
I'm at a point now where I only know enough to cause damage. I have managed to get the Loader in the BCD in the new drive's EPS to point at the new system drive, and it has finally booted into that OS, but its drive letter is not C, and the old system drive is still listed as Boot in diskmgmt (what defines that?) which means Windows won't allow me to change it so that I can then flip C over to my new System volume. Plus, I feel like there's a load of stuff in the BCD I didn't touch, which has the potential to break something in the future!

Comment: The only thing you should have to modify is the OSDevice field.  The GUI string can remain the same since that is the BCD GUI, not anything connected to EFI.  You have not provide any information to identify the string for you.

Comment: And the ApplicationDevice at the top doesn't matter?

And are you referring to nothing to help identify the GUID of the OS volume? The current entry doesn't use a GUID so I didn't think to look for that.

Comment: InheritedObjects, RecoverySequence, AssociatedResumeObject are all BCD GUIDs.  Yes;  THe ApplicationDevice and OSDevice would be the exact string

Comment: OK well the windows system volume I want to boot from is bc64a44b-e5b2-11ed-83d9-74563c62c498 - do I just put that instead of the \device\harddisk\volume7 string, delimited by { }?

Comment: That’s the BCD GUID of the BCD for the partition you want to boot to, thought, you wanted to modify the existing entry. Otherwise you don’t need Visual BCD to make the changes

Comment: Yeah modifying the existing entry is fine, sorry, didn't realise what I said above implied otherwise. So can I just change both of those device entries to that GUID for the new windows volume? Will that fix the problem in the OP about it still having C assigned to the old system volume windows claims is a boot volume and won't allow me to change its drive letter assignment?